# Possible to access Intel Matrix Raid 1 partition from chipset without ICH*R?

Tags: raid, data-recovery, intel-rst

I have got 2 HDDs that were part of an Intel Matrix Raid (now "Rapid Storage Technology") where I had it setup as half RAID 0 and half RAID 1.

The motherboard had an ICH9R chipset I think.

The motherboard has now died and I have **replaced it with a chipset that is NOT an ICHxR**  (Its a ICH10 + G43).

My question is, can I still get to my RAID 1 partition to recover data **without** using another ICHxR chipset?

The drives in question show up in disk manager as "RAW Healthy (Primary Partition)" (I think this is the RAID 0 part... it has a drive letter but when I open it Windows says it needs formatting to use). The other part shows up simply as "Unallocated". I think this is the RAID 1 part.

Perhaps I can just try creating a new Simple disk in the RAID 1 part and see if I can read the data?

Answer (score 0):

That should not be a problem for the RAID1 partition. I've had cases where the ICH settings will revert to non raid in the bios and I ended up with with 2 separate drives in Windows. One was exactly as before. The other appeared as many new drive letters. Now in my case I just had single RAID1 volume. I would recommend using Ubuntu Rescue Remix and ntfsclone to move your data, but you can just try plugging one of the the disks along Windows install. That should work too.

If there are problems reading the partition table you will need something like TestDisk or FindNTFS

Comment: It does seem to be a problem. My RAID 1 partitions show up as RAW, but maybe thats because I am using the "Matrix" feature (mix of both RAID 0 and RAID 1 on two disks).